# The verb and noun used to indicate that an error has been seen

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

I am writing a software program that displays a list of error messages and I want to tell users that an error message "can be marked as seen". For this I would like to describe the action taken by the user as a **verb**. Eg. "*verb* this error".

**Edit - additional information**: When the user has chosen this action the error will disappear from the list of error messages though it is still possible to find it through other means. This means the list of error messages will be curated by the user over time to show error messages that are current and still of interest.

When the error message have been "marked as seen" I would like to show that the error message has a "receipt" or similar **noun** to indicate that it has been seen. Eg. "Only show errors without *noun*". Alternatively I could use a negation of the previously mentioned **verb** eg. "Only show un-*verb*ed errors"

**Edit - additional information:** It is possible to find the source of the error message and view more details about the source in question. Here all error messages will be visible but the ones that have been "marked as seen" will have a marker of some sort to show that the error message have been "*verbed*".

I hope this makes more sense after the edit. This is an attempt to be more specific so as to avoid answers that vary a lot, as per @KannE 's comment.

If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Marked to ignore?

Comment: But first, you mean "error message/ error notification" not "error" that has been seen.

Comment: You can then say "Display unread error messages."

Comment: @jxh I actually want to indicate that "I do not have to see that error message again". So I think _read_ is a bit off but it's a nice short and descriptive word .

Comment: @KannE I often think of _flag_ in a more negative way like "flagged for deletion" and "flag inappropriate message" or something like that. This is more to let user indicate "I got this, don't you worry".

Comment: @Kris With regards to your first comment, would that also be true when the error is still being observed (still going on/happening/still there)?

Comment: @KannE Can you give me an example? I am not sure I fully understand what you mean by "...with the root --NOTE--".

Comment: Appears this question could better be asked on one of SE's computer sites.

Comment: @lbf One would think so, but as far as I remember Stack Overflow encourage you to ask questions that has a single correct and technical answer and one that is not subject to the _opinions_ of other users. In my case I am open for opinions as well :)

Comment: @KannE Yes I just want to "[Verb] this error message". The reason being that the errors are being displayed all the time unless the user "[Verb] this error message". It for a dashboard display with a list of all currently active errors in a list to the side. Some of those errors are desirable to "mute". Hey wait a minute... there's a new verb "mute" :)

Comment: I can see that the question has been put on hold as "primarily opinion-based". I am not sure I understand why this is happening as this site specifically mention it is for asking questions about "Word choice and usage" on [https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic] . I need help to find the correct word to use in a specific context. As I am not a native English speaker I cannot provide any options to choose from. Please consider reopening (un-holding) this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Acknowledge**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acknowledge) this error:

> to disclose knowledge of or agreement with
>
> Please *acknowledge* receipt of this letter.

By extension, "only show errors without *acknowledgement*," or "only show errors that have not been *acknowledged*."

Comment: Funny thing, that was the first one that came to my mind, but I needed someone to come up with some alternatives because my project manager does not like the sound of it. I though "acknowledge this error" as the action to mute an error, and "only show unacknowledged errors" as the filter option was pretty sound and correct English.

Comment: @Bjarne Well, your question didn't say to *not* answer with *acknowledge*. ;) I believe your project manager is wrong.

Comment: No I specifically avoided mentioning any existing progress I have made on the topic as I would like all you wonderful people to chip in with unbiased suggestions :D

Comment: Another funny thing. I my native language the word _receipt_ can be changed to a verb. But when I "back-translate" that with google translate I get back _acknowledge_.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could try *notarize* or *certify* for verb forms of *receipt*, but is this really what you are after?

Comment: @jxh Nah, I think that sounds way too formal. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: *Cross off* is less formal.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you actually want is to mark the error messages in a sort of *queue* (let's say *queue 1*) as "dealt with" so that they no longer need to be shown in a specific dashboard/screen meant for showing *new* errors (the ones that have not earlier been dealt with). The messages which have been seen [dealt with] in this dashboard will probably move to a different *queue* (say *queue 2*) but that is immaterial for the dashboard in question. One word which works as both a verb and noun for this purpose is ***action***.

> An error "can be ***actioned*** [marked as seen (dealt with)]".
>   the error has an
>   ***action*** ["receipt" or similar noun to indicate that it has been seen
>   (dealt with)] against it.
>   Eg. "Only show errors without ***action*** [noun]".
>   eg.
>   "Only show ***unactioned*** [un-verbed] errors"

ODO:

> **[action](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/action)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1** [mass noun] The fact or process of doing something, typically to achieve an aim.
>
> ‘I did in fact take action at that time on advice from officials to
>   address these concerns.’
>
> **[action](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/action)**
>   *VERB*
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>   Take action on; deal with.
>
> ‘your request will be **actioned**’
>
> ‘Anything that is pressed on the keyboard while it is in sleep mode,
>   however, is finally **actioned** after the computer has detected it
>   again.’

Wiktionary:

> **[unactioned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unactioned)**
>   *Adjective*
>
> Not having been actioned; regarding which nothing has been done.
>
> Under no circumstances should anonymous letters remain on file
>   **unactioned**.

Comment: Your understanding of the situation is quiet good. The english version of this software will however be available to many populations who's native language is not English. Therefore I think the verb _actioned_ will lead to some confusion as (at least for myself) _action_ is mostly heard as a noun not a verb.